# Is there a benefit to stacks of allies in Kairobotica?

Tags: kairobotica

In Kairobotica, you gain Power Allies by researching items, which are consumed in the process. Out of curiosity, I researched one I already had and now I have a stack of two, but I haven't noticed any mechanical effects. As the items have other uses, I would very much like to know if this is beneficial or not.

Does having more than one of a given Ally have effects in battle, or is it just a backup in case you lose them?

Answer (score 1):

If you lose a battle and you're with a power ally, you will lose it, and that's pretty much why we can stack them.